# Convert Cleverhans v3.1.0 to TF version >= 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, cleverhans

I am trying to replicate previous research with code which uses Cleverhans v3.1.0 which itself is uses TF v1. I have converted the original code using tf_upgrade_v2, but when it calls cleverhans I still get AttributeErrors. Is there a way to upgrade a package using TF v1 during or after install?

I've tried downloading cleverhans and upgrading the .py files and running setup.py, but I get ModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'cleverhans'.

I installed cleverhans as:

```
python -m pip                                
 install "git+https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans&subdirectory=cleverhans_v3.1.0"
```

I have an M2 Pro which is preventing me from installing a virtual TF v 1.15. I have also tried various workarounds through both pyenv and brew without success.